# How to make Keras custom layer without using Tensofrlow tensors?

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer, tensor

I want to make a custom layer which takes image as an input, transforms it to string of a certain kind, than performs some complicated calculations with this string and transforms it back to image. These functions represent images as numpy arrays.

As far as I know, Keras custom layers should utilize Tensorflow tensors and operations over them. But in this case it seems to be impossible to write my functions in such format.

So, can I somehow just put my function into the model code?

Comment: Gradients need to be propagated through your layer, and TensorFlow functions allow for that, if you do not use them, then training is no longer possible.

Comment: So the only way is to rewrite all 200 lines of my code in tensorflow tensors?

Comment: Given the little information available, I would say yes, we do not know what your code does.

Comment: Well, it reads image to dot-bracket string and performs some calculations using the Bio library